# Windows To Go Device using Windows Technical Preview

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-to-go

I have successfully made a Windows To Go Device by the steps in this Technet forum post:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6991.windows-to-go-step-by-step.aspx

Note: I used a host machine running Windows Technical Preview already to make this device, since older versions (Windows 8/8.1) of DISM don't work for imaging Windows Technical Preview Installation.

Everything works fine. The device on which Windows To Go is running is a high-speed USB 3.0 HDD, so there is no significant performance difference. However, while updating to the new build 9860, the upgrade fails stating that you can't install it to a USB Flash Drive.

Question 1) Does this problem has anything to do with the fact that I am NOT using the enterprise version of Windows Technical Preview, the only version which "technically" supports Windows To Go feature.

Question 2) My host machine (which I used to create Windows TP) has been updated to Build 9860. Should I use DISM to capture the image of this updated build and use it to image the WTG HDD device? Can I get detailed instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Is the HDD a /supported/ Windows To Go drive? There is a restricted list based on how he drive presents itself to the OS. Also, yes the Tech Preview for Enterprise is most likely a requirement.